# Entity A depends on Entity B, how to send all entity's B info to POST Create method of Entity A using MVC Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've got a User class which has a Name (unique and required) a password (required) and a Profile (required). The Profile class has a Name which is unique and required too. Both classes have an Id that acts as primary Key while generating data base using code first.

I want to allow the creation of new users in my page, here is some code to do this:

**Controller**

```
        // GET: Users/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        populateViewBagWithProfilesAsSelectListItem();
        return View();
    }

    private void populateViewBagWithProfilesAsSelectListItem()
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> profiles = db.Profiles.ToList().
            Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                Text = x.Name
            });
        ViewBag.Profiles = profiles;
    }

    // POST: Users/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Name,Password,Profile")] User user)
    {
        user.Profile = db.Profiles.Find(user.Profile.Id);
        ModelState.Clear();
        TryValidateModel(user);
        lock (UsersLocker)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

        populateViewBagWithProfilesAsSelectListItem();
        return View(user);
    }
```

**Create View**

```
@model ProceduresRecord.Web.MVC.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Crear";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())

{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Usuario</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Profile, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Profile.Id, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Profiles, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Profile.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Crear" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Volver a la Lista", "Index")
</div>
```

this results in this page:

[image: Create user View]

As you can see I populate the profiles from data base, I show the profiles names to the user, once he picks one and clicks on create, an Id of that profile is sent to the POST method Create in the controller. Then I struggle to get the complete Profile from database using the provided Id, I assign the complete profile to the user and re validate the ModelState (so that it changes to true... it was false because the profile didn't have a name until now).
It all seems to work, but I was wondering...

Isn't there a better way to do this? I mean, I already got the profiles from data base when populating the html select, wouldn't it be awesome to be able to send the complete profile to the POST in one shot and avoid this code:

```
        user.Profile = db.Profiles.Find(user.Profile.Id);
        ModelState.Clear();
        TryValidateModel(user);
```

If there is some way, please tell me!

P.D: I'm trying to learn MVC and Code First on my own, any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Do not use data models in your view, especially when editing. Create a view model the properties for `Name`, Password` and `SelectedProfile` - see answer by CodingYoshi (and none of the last 3 lines of code in your question is required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your ModelState errors are. But you should probably have a property on your `User` enitity called `ProfileId`.  If not you should probably add one. Then you can change your Views profile dropdown to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProfileId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Profiles, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Then change `Profile` in your `Bind(Include)` of the Create action to `ProfileId` and your Create action can just be

```
// POST: Users/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Name,Password,ProfileId")] User user)
{
    lock (UsersLocker)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }

    populateViewBagWithProfilesAsSelectListItem();
    return View(user);
}
```

If it were me, I'd create a new view model class `UserViewModel` with the Id, Name, Password and ProfileId properties and pass that back and forth to the View.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly my mistake, I only had a property of type Profile in my User, but was missing ProfileId of type int, I didn't know that by convention I should have both... I didn't even imagine EF did all that work alone only by having those two properties. Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

When you are creating your user, you do not need the complete `Profile` but only the id of the `Profile`. Therefore, you only need to post the user information and the `Profile` Id. When you create a new user and set the `Profile` Id property, EF will figure it out for you: If the profile exists with that key it will use it, otherwise it will complain that it cannot find an item with the provided foreign key.

Also I would create a model for the view which will look like this:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    // This will be the selected profile id
    public string SelectedProfileId { get; set; }

    // fill this with all the profiles
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

Each `SelectListItem` can be created like this:

```
new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = ProfileId, // Whatever the property is
        Text = ProfileName,  // this will be displayed in dropdown
    });
```

In your controller create an instance of that and send it to your view.

In your view create the dropdown like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedProfileId, 
                new SelectList(m.AvailableProfiles)), 
                "Select Profile")
```

Then in the post get the selected profile id from the `SelectedProfileId` property.

Comment: Setting `Selected = true` does nothing at all when you bind to a model property (its ignored by the `DropDownListFor()` method because its the value of `SelectedProfileId` which determines what is selected) - otherwise  this is the correct approach

Comment: Thank you! Even if JamieD77's answer was more suitable to my lack of knowledge, you answer proved very helpful too! I didn't know how to use view models, but it turned out to be very simple and powerful. Thanks!